Group Product going "Out of Stock"
I have created a grouped product with 5 simple products attached to it.  Each of those has a QTY of 15.  However, at random, the grouped product turns Out of Stock without any reason.  There have not been sales of this product.  I flip it back, and save, and then re-index, and its fixed.  In Stock.
Has anyone seen this or can offer a suggestion on how to solve it?

Ensure "Manage Stock" is enabled for the grouped and simple products, and that the grouped product's stock status is set to "In Stock."
